# Meaning of “modulo the identity matrix”

Tags: group-theory, isometry

I’m reading about $PSL(2,R)$. Can someone explain the meaning of: the matrices in $SL(2,R)$ “modulo plus or minus the identity matrix.” I understand the first part, but what does the quoted part mean? thanks

I'm new to math stackex; trying to get the hang of it. I'm attempting to respond to all 4 responses to my initial 10/22 Q (paragraph 1 above). Thanks Somos, J.W., lulu, and Ben for extremely fast answers. (Some of this is over my head, so I'd be grateful for concrete examples whenever possible. Thanks.)

1. Is there a homomorphism from (2,) to (2,) with kernel +- the identity matrix?
2. Is this homomorphism the squaring function? If not, what's the homomorphism?
3. The 2x2 matrices ([3,1],[-7,-2]) and ([-3,-1],[7,2]) are both in (2,). But only one is in (2,), right? Which one and why?

Thanks very much for your help, Somos (is the this the right way to respond to you?)

I understand that (2,) can be viewed as a group of cosets (each coset containing a matrix and its negative) where the kernal {+I and -I} is the identity. Each coset, I suppose, would represent one linear fractional transformation. (The 2x2 matrices ([3,1],[-7,-2]) and ([-3,-1],[7,2]) represent the same transformation.)

However, can't (2,) also be viewed as a group of individual 2x2 matrices where I is the identity element? If so, which of the above 2x2 matrices is in (2,)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's a group quotient; matrices that are related to each other by multiplication by minus the identity matrix are considered equivalent

Comment: Note that $\{\pm \mathbb 1\}$ is a normal subgroup (central, even). This is then just the ordinary quotient.

Comment: It is formally the quotient group $\text{SL}(2, \mathbb{R}) $, but informally (and most useful) it is just $\text{SL} (2, \mathbb{R} ) $ with matrices $A$ being identified as $-A$ in the same sort of way identify elements of $\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z} $.

Comment: Sorry if this is the wrong place for this; I'm new to math.stackex and I don't know where to ask this (I thought at Mathematics meta, but I can't ask a Q there without 5 reputation points. 1) If this is the wrong place, where should I ask Qs like these? 2) I posted the Q above about (2,). Comments and 1 ans. were posted. How do I respond to a specific comment and how do I respond to an answer? 3) I got the idea that I should respond to an answer by editing my original Q. Is that right? 4) If I edit my original Q a month later, how will anyone see my edits so they might respond? Thanks.

Comment: Undoubtedly you have seen the use of cosets in elementary number theory. Like in $\Bbb{Z}_7$ you have $\overline{1}=\overline{8}$ because the cosets $1+7\Bbb{Z}$ and $8+\Bbb{Z}$ are the same coset. But (at least technically) you should not say that $1$ is an element of $\Bbb{Z}_7$. That would rarely lead to a misunderstanding, but the elements really are cosets. It's the same here. Technically neither $([3,1],[-7,-2])$ nor $([-3,-1],[7,2])$ is an element of $PSL_2$. It would be more accurate to write $\overline{([3,1],[-7,-2])}=\overline{([-3,-1],[7,2])}$.

Comment: So, no $PSL_2(\Bbb{R})$ is not a subgroup of $2\times2$ matrices. Yes, there is a homomorphism from $SL_2$ to $PSL_2$ much like there always is a homomorphism from a group $G$ to $G/H$ when $H\unlhd G$. It is not squaring, because squaring does not satisfy the homomorphism condition in general.

Comment: Somewhat surprisingly there is also a homomorphism from $PSL_2$ to $SL_3$. It maps the coset of $$A=\pmatrix {a&b\cr c&d\cr}$$ to
$$
\pmatrix
{a^2 & 2 a b & b^2 \cr
 a c & a d+b c & b d \cr
 c^2 & 2 c d & d^2 \cr}.
$$
I wouldn't worry about that much at this point. You do see that this mapping sends both $A$ and $-A$ to the same $3\times3$ matrix, meaning that the mapping is well defined.

Comment: @Mathguy: Upvoted your question. Now you have 11 points and can ask. Enjoy! :).

Answer (score 2):

You asked about the quote

> the matrices in $SL(2,R)$ modulo plus or minus the identity matrix.

In the context of $\,PSL(2,R),\,$ a matrix $\,A={a\, b\choose c\,d}\,$
is mapped to the [linear fractional transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_fractional_transformation) $\,z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}\,$
which is a homomorphism of groups as in Wikipedia [SL(2,R)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2(R)).
The matrices $\,A\,$ and $\,-A\,$ both map to the same
transformation (in general, any scalar multiple of $\,A\,$ maps
to the same transformation). The identity matrix and its negative form a normal subgroup of $\,SL(2,R)\,$ whose quotient is $\,PSL(2,R)\,$ where,
indeed, $\,A\,$ and $\,-A\,$ are identified in the quotient.

Of course, if $\,R=\mathbb{Z}\,$ then this is the only identification
of matrices when passing to linear transformations. For other rings, there may be more identifications based on units in the ring $\,R\,$ as
indicated in the Wikipedia article.

You asked:

> 2. Is this homomorphism the squaring function? If not, what's the homomorphism?

The "squaring" function is not a homomorphism.

> 3. The 2x2 matrices ([3,1],[-7,-2]) and ([-3,-1],[7,2]) are both in (2,). But only one is in (2,), right? Which one and why?

The elements of (2,) are cosets (or equivalence classes) and each
coset consists of a matrix and its negative, so **both** are in the
same coset of (2,).

Comment: I'm new to math stackex; trying to get the hang of it. I'm attempting to respond to all 4 responses to my initial 10/22 Q. Thanks Somos, J.W., lulu, and Ben for extremely fast answers. (Some of this is over my head, so I'd be grateful for concrete examples whenever possible. Thanks.) 1) Is there a homomorphism from (2,) to (2,) with kernel +- the identity matrix? 2) Is this homomorphism the squaring function? If not, what's the homomorphism? 3) The 2x2 matrices ([3,1],[-7,-2]) and ([-3,-1],[7,2]) are both in (2,). But only one is in (2,), right? Which one and why?

Comment: Please don't use comments for this. Ask your new questions in the body of the original question.

Comment: Thanks very much, Somos.

Comment: Better yet, if you have a new Question, ask a new Question.  You can include a link back to this Question in the body of your new Question to help provide context.  If you found that the Answer to a Question you asked "goes over your head," it might mean you need to do more research about the problem before posting, or in some cases to ask a more threshold Question about terminology, e.g. what does "quotient of a group" mean.

Comment: Thanks, hardmath.

Comment: @Mathguy: I gave an answer in which I tried to break it down as much as possible. Please let me know if it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, in a quotient $G/H$, two elements $g,g'$ are in the same coset iff (def.)
$$ab^{-1} \in H $$.

In our case, per this definition, for $G:=SL(2,  R)$ ; $H:=\{ I,-I\}$,:

Two matrices $M, M' $are equivalent, aka , in the same coset iff :
$$MM'= \pm Id$$ , i.e., if $MM'=Id$ or $MM'= -Id $

Multiplying each equation by $M^{-1}$, this comes down to $M, M'$ being in the same coset iff:

$M'=M^{-1}$ or $M'=-M^{-1}$ .

This means we collapse a matrix and its inverse to a single element in the coset.

I leave to you the exercise of trying this with $S_3$ the permutation group of
order 3 , see what you get for $S_3/ \pm Id$